# Threads on Lazarus Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, multithreading, lazarus

I'm having problems when I run an application using threads, on windows works fine, but when I run it on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 my app crashes.

It's a very small app just to understand threads.

when the thread is created my app crashes.

here is the code:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  ComCtrls;

type

{ TMyThread }

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    fStatusText: string;
    procedure CambiaLabel();
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
  end;

{ TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
     miHilo: TThread;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TMyThread }
procedure TMyThread.CambiaLabel();
begin
    Form1.Label1.Caption:=fStatusText;

    Form1.ProgressBar1.StepIt;

    if Form1.ProgressBar1.Position = Form1.ProgressBar1.Max then begin
       Form1.miHilo.Terminate;
       Form1.ProgressBar1.Position := 0;
    end;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  newStatus : string;
begin
  fStatusText := 'TMyThread comenzando...';
  fStatusText := 'TMyThread Corriendo ...';
  while (not Terminated) and (true {any condition required}) do begin

    //here goes the code of the main thread loop

    Synchronize(@CambiaLabel);

  end;
end;

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: boolean);
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if miHilo <> nil then begin
    ShowMessage('Ya se esta ejecutando');
  end
  else begin
    miHilo := TMyThread.Create(false);
  end;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if miHilo <> nil then begin
     miHilo.Terminate;
     ShowMessage('Hilo terminado');
     miHilo:=nil;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

end.
```

here the images with the error messages: [error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOdVy.png)

Comment: Try setting the FreeOnTerminate property after calling the inherited create.

Comment: Also, you may need to call 'resume' as the last line of the ctor - don't know any Lazarus, (Delphi guy) - the ctor may resume the thread anyway, or not?

Comment: ..and yes, the error message doesn't make much sense to me either.  Maybe it's some artifact of the debugger?

Comment: ..or, of course, maybe your 'code of the main thread loop' may be err.. 'sub-optimal' :).  What happens if you put a 'while(true) do sleep(1000);' line at the top of the execute method - does it still blow up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, I was missing something on my .lpr file of my project, I you use threads os OS Unix like Linux, OsX, freebsd, you had to add a line on your .lpr file:

This is the normal file:

```
program project1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}


uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, Unit1
  { you can add units after this };
  .
  .
  .
```

and this is the line you have to add    **{$define UseCThreads}**

so your file should look like this:

program project1;

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$define UseCThreads}

uses
  {$IFDEF UNIX}{$IFDEF UseCThreads}
  cthreads,
  {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}
  Interfaces, // this includes the LCL widgetset
  Forms, Unit1
  { you can add units after this };
  .
  .
  .
```

and that's it now works, thanks for the answers and the tips ;D

Comment: You can also add the define in your project file. Note there is another such construct for locale data (unit clocale), but that is not preprepared in the dpr atm.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I've had a brief look at the project options and can't seem to locate the place to add -D options. I'm probably being quite blind, but could you elaborate on the place?